# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: UCNV_FROM_U_CALLBACK_ESCAPE_44

Tags: browser, webkit, icu

I am getting this error when I try to run my project with the  lib webkit shared library

The whole error is

> symbol lookup error: ./lib/libwebkit-1.0.so.2: undefined symbol:
>   UCNV_FROM_U_CALLBACK_ESCAPE_44

I just want to look for what might cause this error as I didn't find anything useful on google to tell me what is the problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

It turn out that when I recompile my ICU library "properly" it worked again